# c3.js how to get a onclick event for DataGroups

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, c3

I have been using c3.js and cant figure out how to get a JavaScript event for onClick of the Data group labels which is displayed in X Axis.

Basically i need event to which I can register a event handler in the below Circled area.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method, as of yet, in c3js for adding onClick events on ticks.

But you can directly use d3:

```
d3.selectAll('.tick')
  .on('click', function(value,index){
      alert('You clicked a tick.');
  });
```

This will add an event that will fire when you click a tick.

jsfiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Lc3447Lb/1/

Source: https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/761