# how to get custom Label in c3.js onclick event

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, bar-chart, c3.js

Adding Image for better understanding. [image]

Used below function inside data in c3.js bar chart

```
onclick: function(d,i){
  console.log("onclick",d,i);
},
```

**Current Output:**

```
  x: 1,
  value: 200,
  id: "August",
  index: 1,
  name: "August"
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
  x: 1,
  value: 200,
  id: "August",
  index: 1,
  name: "August", 
  label: cable // or E-commerce // or G2C // or IT etc.
}
```

I also went through [c3.js how to get a onclick event for DataGroups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742630/c3-js-how-to-get-a-onclick-event-for-datagroups) but in this example, only index numbers are getting. I need to extract label s shown in the image.